# Как в Linux запустить perl-скрипт используя XAMPP?

Tags: linux, perl

При переходе на Linux заменил Денвер XAMPP'oм. Виртуальные хосты настроил, все работает, кроме **perl-скриптов**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо сделать для работы perl-скриптов на виртуальном хосте в XAMPP.

Также буду благодарен за ссылку по теме.

Comment: Врообще-то в XAMPP и так всё для этого сделано. Что конкретно не работает, что в логах?

Comment: скрипт лежит в папке cgi-bin, но когда пытаюсь в браузере запустить скрипт site.ru/cgi-bin/test.plвылезает 404 ошибка о том. что файл не найден.

Comment: В логах-то что? Что в настройках хоста по поводу `ScriptAlias`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а если переименовать скрипт из *.pl в* .cgi (и соответственно так к нему и обращаться - site.ru/cgi-bin/test.cgi) ?

Comment: Пока вы не покажете логи и настройки хоста это всё гадание на кофейной гуще. Ну попробуйте, вдруг у вас в конфигах .cgi, а не .pl прописано... Даже если и поможет - так и угадывать каждый раз что не так вместо того, чтобы один раз понять и разобраться?